# PL/SQL function returns multiple rows

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I Have a function in Oracle SQL Database like this

```
create or replace function DEF_ID(
in_checkid IN SQLTEXTDEFN.SQLID%type
) 
return varchar2
as
sql_stmt clob;
ret varchar2(254);
begin
   begin 
     execute immediate 'select SQLTEXT from SQLTEXTDEFN where sqlid=:1'
         into sql_stmt
         using in_checkid;
       begin
         execute immediate sql_stmt into ret;
         EXCEPTION
                WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
                    RETURN 'NO DATA FOUND';
                when others then
                    return substr(sqlerrm,1,200);
       end; 
            EXCEPTION
                WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
                    RETURN 'NO CHECK FOUND';
                when others then
                    return substr(sqlerrm,1,200);
            END;
return ret;
end;
```

The SQLTEXTDEFN table is a table with different SQL statements. When I execute this function a get the response of the SQL statement. In certain cases I get an error:

```
ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows
```

I only wants the first row as result if multiple rows are fetched.

Comment: Modify SQLTEXT so that it returns only one row.

Answer (score 1):

Limit your result to only one row:

```
execute immediate 'select SQLTEXT from SQLTEXTDEFN where sqlid=:1 and rownum = 1'
```

If SQLTEXT is a varchar2, it's even safer to just do a MAX on it:

```
execute immediate 'select MAX(SQLTEXT) from SQLTEXTDEFN where sqlid=:1'
```

That will prevent both exceptions for duplicate rows and no rows. But you can't do that if it's a CLOB. In that case, add exception handling to quietly handle NO_DATA_FOUND.

Comment: In fact it is not that query that return me different rows, but the execute after that: execute immediate sql_stmt into ret;

Comment: Same SQL, same issue, only this time you're lacking the USING clause, not sure how that's even parsing. You may not have transcribed to your question the exact code you ran. Why are you executing the same SQL twice like this?